# Random Crash no logs found, weird symptoms

Tags: crash

I am getting some random crashing.
I am running a lenovo X1 (SSD) with Ubuntu 14.04.

The symptom I get is my entire machine locks up and becomes unresponsive, cannot get into any tty terminal etc. Requires Hard boot.

I see nothing in the /var/logs to detect the error.

The other weird issue, if I am running my text editor ( RubyMine) when the crash happens, The file I am working on has all it's content deleted.

I suspect it is a HDD issue? but when i run
sudo badblocks -v  Nothing is reported.

Wondering what else I might do? What logs I might check?

Crash happens often. Usually only when I am working with multiple programs open for a while.